# Is running two (or more) programs at the same time or multithreading in one program faster?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am designing my first multiplayer game, and in my current server implementation I am just running multiple instances of the same file for each client. Compared to running just one file which is multithreaded, which would be faster? Or is it the same speed?

Comment: The answer: "It depends". Well thought multithreading is gonna be faster, but if you write it poorly it can potentially deadlock and freeze your program altogether.

Comment: The general rule would be to use multiprocessing when the processes are CPU intensive. Multithreading is more suited to I/O based activity

Comment: For the multithreaded case, be aware of the Python GIL and how it limits a Python app to only allowing one thread to execute at a time.